# Why the variable doesn't change even if it should?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

someVar=0

tac /etc/hosts | while IFS= read line; do
    echo "$someVar : $line"
    someVar=$((someVar+1))
done
echo "Finally: $someVar"
```

When I run it by using `./test.sh`, I have this this output:

```
0 : ::1             localhost ipv6-localhost ipv6-loopback
1 : fe00::0         ipv6-localnet
2 : ff00::0         ipv6-mcastprefix
Finally: 0
```

Why the var `someVar` is at the end 0 even if before it was 2, even if as described [here](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-functions/#:%7E:text=Variables%20Scope,-Global%20variables%20are&text=In%20Bash%2C%20all%20variables%20by,same%20name%20in%20different%20functions.) it should be global and as it's well executed before the var is incremented?

Comment: [BashFAQ 24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer.

Instead of creating a subshell with the `|`, we can inject it at the end. It were not working with the basic `< $(cmd)`, but with `< <(cmd)` it works fine.

The final script is like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

someVar=0

while IFS= read line; do
    echo "$someVar : $line"
    someVar=$((someVar+1))
done < <(tac /etc/hosts) # <---- changes here
echo "Finally: $someVar"
```

Output:

```
0 : ::1             localhost ipv6-localhost ipv6-loopback
1 : fe00::0         ipv6-localnet
2 : ff00::0         ipv6-mcastprefix
Finally: 3 # not 0 !
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Why the var someVar is at the end 0?

[ShellCheck – shell script analysis tool](https://www.shellcheck.net/) has the answer:

> Modification of someVar is local (to subshell caused by pipeline).

```
$ shellcheck myscript
 
Line 5:
tac /etc/hosts | while IFS= read line; do
                            ^-- SC2162 (info): read without -r will mangle backslashes.
 
Line 7:
    someVar=$((someVar+1))
    ^-- SC2030 (info): Modification of someVar is local (to subshell caused by pipeline).
 
Line 9:
echo "Finally: $someVar"
               ^-- SC2031 (info): someVar was modified in a subshell. That change might be lost.

$
```

Comment: Ok so with the `-r` option it will works as it will not create a subshell?

Comment: I've no idea...

Comment: I just tested and it doesn't